# Why is my stopwatch adding fixed amount of time when I refresh?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, vue.js

I have a Vue.js Script is Adding time to my stopwatch once I refresh the page - Always adds an additional 6 hours. The script is simply a button that tracks time when clicked, and post the time to a django model once stopped. I am able to track time fine, but when I refresh the page, I come back to seeing 6 hours added to my stopwatch:

Vue.js Script:

```
var NavbarApp = {
            data() {
                return {
                    seconds: {{ active_entry_seconds }},
                    trackingTime: false,
                    showTrackingModal: false,
                    timer: null,
                    entryID: 0,
                    startTime: '{{ start_time }}'
                }
            },
            delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
            methods: {
                startTimer() {
                    fetch('/apps/api/start_timer/', {
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                            'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
                        }
                    })
                    .then((response) => {
                        return response.json()
                    })
                    .then((result) => {
                        this.startTime = new Date()
                        this.trackingTime = true

                        this.timer = setInterval(() => {
                            this.seconds = (new Date() - this.startTime) / 1000
                        }, 1000)
                    })
                },
                stopTimer() {
                    fetch('/apps/api/stop_timer/', {
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                            'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
                        }
                    })
                    .then((response) => {
                        return response.json()
                    })
                    .then((result) => {
                        this.entryID = result.entryID
                        this.showTrackingModal = true
                        this.trackingTime = false

                        window.clearTimeout(this.timer)
                    })
                },
                discardTimer() {
                    fetch('/apps/api/discard_timer/', {
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                            'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
                        }
                    })
                    .then((response) => {
                        this.seconds = 0
                        this.showTrackingModal = false
                    })
                },
                addLater() {
                    this.seconds = 0
                    this.showTrackingModal = false
                },
                addToTask() {
                    console.log('addToTask')
                    window.location.href = '/apps/track_entry/' + this.entryID + '/'
                }
            },
            mounted() {
                if (this.seconds !== 0) {
                    this.trackingTime = true
                    this.timer = setInterval(() => {
                        this.seconds = (new Date() - new Date(this.startTime)) / 1000
                    }, 1000)
                }
            },
            computed: {
                readableSeconds() {
                    const d = Number(this.seconds);
                    const h = Math.floor(d / 3600);
                    const m = Math.floor(d % 3600 / 60);
                    const s = Math.floor(d % 3600 % 60);

                    const hDisplay = h > 0 ? h + (h == 1 ? "h, " : "h, ") : "";
                    const mDisplay = m > 0 ? m + (m == 1 ? "m, " : "m, ") : "";
                    const sDisplay = s >= 0 ? s + (s == 1 ? "s" : "s") : "";

                    return hDisplay + mDisplay + sDisplay; 
                }
            }
        }

        Vue.createApp(NavbarApp).mount('#navbar-app')
```

HTML:

```
                                                <div class="col-md-auto mt-md-0 mt-4" id="navbar-app">
                                                    <div class="hstack gap-1 flex-wrap">
                                                        <div class="navbar-item" v-if="!trackingTime">
                                                            <div class="buttons">
                                                                <button class="btn btn-success add-btn" @click="startTimer()">
                                                                   Start Timer
                                                                </button>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                            
                                                        <div class="navbar-item" v-else>
                                                            <div class="buttons">
                                                                <div class="buttons">
                                                                    <button class="btn btn-warning add-btn" @click="stopTimer()">
                                                                        [[ readableSeconds ]] (stop)
                                                                    </button>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
```

When I click the button - time is tracking:
[image]

When I refresh the page, 6 additional hours have been added:
[image]

Let me know if I am missing any information or code you may need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django 5.0 handles dates automatically. This means that if your client is in a UTC-6 timezone, it will add 6 hours and store it in UTC time. When you use the date, it will convert it to local time and you will probably have no problems.
If you are using older versions like 4.2 you can just set `USE_TZ = True`.

If this doesn't solve your problem [this doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/i18n/timezones/) should help you. Especially [this section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/i18n/timezones/#std-templatefilter-localtime) on focing local time.
[This](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/timezones/#fixtures) explains what the different results are depending on USE_TZ being true or false.

(I couldn't write a comment because my reputation is too low and I don't know vue.js, sorry.)

Hope I could help.

Comment: Yep, this was the issue. You nailed it - thank you!